# Where to find a list of posts having edit suggestions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, featured-tag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I review pending edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97363/can-i-review-pending-edits)

My question is regarding Stack Overflow. I've recently reached 2k reputation points. I've achieved a privilege that I can approve / reject 'edit' requests by other users, having reputation below 2k. Is there some link or section where I can find the list of posts, having pending requests for 'edit' on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure at what reputation level it becomes available, the queue can be reached from the "review" tab. (I'm afraid only for 5k rep)

Comment: @DanielFischer,Thanks for your quick & correct reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 2k, you can only see pending edits on a post you are currently viewing. This will appear as an `edit (0)` in place of the standard `edit` link.

At 5k, a new [tab will be available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) on the [review page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/review), which will show suggested edits.

At [10k](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), the edit queue will be accessible as part of the moderator tools from the bar across the top of the page, via a counter which will show next to the `review` link.

Comment: I think it is a bit odd to have the difference between 5k and 10k user.

Comment: @nhahtdh But you're the one in the position to find out whether the top-bar counter is shown for 5k users already or not. What do you see on SO?

Comment: @DanielFischer: From what I see there is no counter for 5k user. Only review link.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. Since I see 178 currently, that indicates the counter only gets available at 10k.

Answer (score 3):

At 2k, you can approve/reject edits if you're already on the same page. You will see an `edit(0)` on the post, and you can approve from there.

At 5k, you get access to the queue.

At 10k, you get a counter next to your rep and badges for the queue.

Comment: At 5k, you get the "suggested edits" tab on the /review page. You don't get the queue/counter access directly until 10k

Comment: @jim wrong--a few weeks back, on MSO, I had <10k and could still see the counter

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles approving edits only requires 2k. That part of your answer is correct. It's just the 5k portion I was correcting.

Comment: @jim sorry, mistyped. I meant to say "the counter", see edited comment

Comment: Oh. Did you have 10k before you had <10k?

Comment: With my answer being wrong for 2k users, I nixed it.

Comment: @jim ?? I had around 8k a month back.

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression that the queue/counter was part of the 10k/moderator tools privelege. I don't have >10k on any site, and only >5k on one site, so I've never had access to it, but on the >5k site, I don't have the edit queue up there and need to access it via /review's suggested edit tab

Comment: @jim IIRC, on some sites, the 10k flag counter doesn't show until it's greater than 5 (happens on MSO). Maybe the same applies to the queue? (I can certify that it always shows on MSO and chem.SE)

Comment: @Jim As Manish suspected, the top-bar counter doesn't show when it's smaller than 5, on low-traffic sites that would often be the case, on SO it's a rare occurrence. I don't remember when I got the counter, though.

Comment: Do you have a reference for it not showing up? You are ♦ on Chem, so I expect you would always see it.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84362/167443) assumes 10k, and has not been corrected. Perhaps it is 10k?

Comment: @Manish, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139254/where-to-find-list-of-post-having-edit-suggestions/139256#comment392390_139260 seems to confirm the 10k. (Maybe it's different per site?)

Comment: @daniel ah, thanks. Will edit

Comment: As does [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99844/167443)

Comment: @jim that was from the time when the queue itself was 10k only (both of your links). It used to be 2k:approval,5k:tagwiki queue, 10k:edit queue and counter